# SearchView positions when expanded in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

1.how can i get SearchView left,right,bottom,.. positions when it is expanded in Action Bar,and i am getting the values in normal position.

2.how can give my list of words as search suggestions for a searchview.

Comment: Found a way to align expanded SearchView that works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20146626/56285

Answer (score -1):

You can use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to put searchview in center

```
<item  android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_main"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:title="Search"/>
```

Comment: Does not work for me. Neither does `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` etc.